# jQuery not working in Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Please see my site here: http://tinyurl.com/ouvkj3b

I've included my scripts file ([theme directory]/js/scripts.js) by enqueuing it in functions.php. I can see this has included successfully (line 193), although including directly in the header makes no difference.

The problem is that my jQuery scripts don't seem to do anything... even if I use scripts that I've used previously on other sites.For a test, for now I've just included a simple script: to fade out the main logo when it is clicked.

I'm sure this will be something obvious, but I just can't see the problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

Code for reference:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(function() {
        $('#headline_logo').click(function() {
            $('#headline_logo').fadeToggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the unnecessary `$(function() {` from your code. So that, you get

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#headline_logo').click(function() {
        $('#headline_logo').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```